# An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property MD5

Tags: c#, object

I get the object reference is required on the following code.

The error is on this line: `var pass = Presenter.HelperClass.GetMD5(password);`
Although i don't really see where the problem is.

The helperclass:

```
public class HelperClass
    {
       public string GetMD5(string text)
       {
           MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
           md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));
           byte[] result = md5.Hash;
           StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
           for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
           {
               str.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
           }
           return str.ToString();
       }  
    }
```

My presenter:

```
public class LoginPresenter
    {
       private Emplyer employee = new Emplyer();
       private LoginView1 login = new LoginView1();


       public LoginPresenter(Emplyer employee, LoginView1 login) 
       {
           this.employee = employee;
           this.login = login;
           login.loginpresenter = this;
       }

       private bool isValidUser(string username, string password) 
       {

        var pass = Presenter.HelperClass.GetMD5(password);
        }
}
```

Comment: what don't you understand about the build error?

Comment: mark `HelperClass` and `GetMD5` as `static`

Answer (score 0):

The GetMD5 method is not static.  You need to declare an instance of HelperClass in order to use the GetMD5 method, or change the GetMD5 method to static.